# ngbDropdown not working with cdkDrag Angular 11.0.3

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-cdk-drag-drop

`ngbDropdown` not closing when clicking on menu item. Its working fine outer side `cdkdrag` div but not inside cdkdrag. I tried remove cdkDrag then its working fine. I also tried to change version of `ngbDropdown` and `cdkDrag`.
It's also working fine when using manual installing `bootstrap` with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I added an ID to the button which opens the drop-down. Also, I created a listener for tracking clicking events on anything apart from that button.

```html
<div *ngIf="actions?.length">
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" [placement]="placement">
        <a id="drBtn" class="font-weight-boldest text-muted text-hover-primary pl-3 pb-3" ngbDropdownToggle>
            . . .</a>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="">
            <div *ngFor="let action of actions">
                <button class="dropdown-item"
                        (click)="doAction(action.type)"
                >
                    <span class="navi-icon mr-2" *ngIf="action.icon"><i class="{{action.icon}}"></i></span>
                    {{action.name}}
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export class ActionDropdownComponent {
      @Input('placement') placement: string = "";
      @Input('actions') actions: IAction[];
      @Output() onAction: EventEmitter<IAction> = new EventEmitter<IAction>();
      @ViewChild(NgbDropdown) dropdown: NgbDropdown;

      public doAction(action: IAction) {
         this.onAction.emit(action);
     }

     @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onClick(e) {
        if (e.target.id === 'drBtn') return;
        else
            if (this.dropdown.isOpen())
                this.dropdown.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add some explanation to your answer.